# Unable to merge multiIndexed pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I believe I am ultimately looking for a way to change the dtype of data frame indices.  Please allow me to explain:

Each df is multi-indexed on (the same) four levels.  One level consists of  mixed labels of integers, integer and letters (like D8), and just letters.

However, for df1, the integers within the index labels are surrounded by quotation marks, while for df2, the same integer lables are free of any quotes; i.e.,

```
df1.index.levels[1]  
Index(['Z5', '02', '1C', '26', '2G', '2S', '30', '46', '48', '5M', 'CSA', etc...'],     dtype='object', name='BMDIV')

df2.index.levels[1]  
Index([   26,    30,    46,    48,    72,  '1C',  '5M',  '7D',  '7Y',  '8F',
        '8J',  'AN',  'AS',  'C3',  'CA', etc.
      dtype='object', name='BMDIV')
```

When I try to merge these tables

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I get:

> TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not map

Is there a way to change, for example, the type of label in df2 so that the numbers are in quotes and therefore presumably match the corresponding labels in df1?

Comment: You may want to consider addressing this issue when you first create these DataFrames, as opposed to immediately before the merge.  Looking at `df1`, it appears that you have zero padded integer strings, e.g. `'02'`.  If this was converted to a regular integer in `df2` it would just be `2`, and converting it to a string would not give the zero padding, and the merge wouldn't occur between `'02'` and `'2'`.  You could add an additional step of zero padding single characters when you convert to strings, but it seems like it'd be best to just get the correct dtype upon initialization.

Comment: Definitely good practice @root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to change the level values is to build a new MultiIndex and re-assign it to `df.index`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'index':[ 26, 30, 46, 48, 72, '1C', '5M', '7D', '7Y', 
               '8F', '8J', 'AN', 'AS', 'C3', 'CA'], 
     'foo':1, 'bar':2})
df = df.set_index(['index', 'foo'])
level_values = [df.index.get_level_values(i) for i in range(index.nlevels)]
level_values[0] = level_values[0].astype(str)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(level_values)
```

which makes the level values strings:

```
In [53]: df.index.levels[0]
Out[56]: 
Index(['1C', '26', '30', '46', '48', '5M', '72', '7D', '7Y', '8F', '8J', 'AN',
       'AS', 'C3', 'CA'],
      dtype='object', name='index')
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the somewhat low-level messiness by using `reset_index` and `set_value`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'index':[ 26, 30, 46, 48, 72, '1C', '5M', '7D', '7Y', 
               '8F', '8J', 'AN', 'AS', 'C3', 'CA'], 
     'foo':1, 'bar':2})
df = df.set_index(['index', 'foo'])

df = df.reset_index('index')
df['index'] = df['index'].astype(str)
df = df.set_index('index', append=True)
df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=0)
```

which again produces string-valued index level values:

```
In [67]: df.index.levels[0]
Out[67]: 
Index(['1C', '26', '30', '46', '48', '5M', '72', '7D', '7Y', '8F', '8J', 'AN',
       'AS', 'C3', 'CA'],
      dtype='object', name='index')
```

---

Of these two options, `using_MultiIndex` is faster:

```
N = 1000
def make_df(N):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'index': np.random.choice(np.array(
            [26, 30, 46, 48, 72, '1C', '5M', '7D', '7Y', 
             '8F', '8J', 'AN', 'AS', 'C3', 'CA'], dtype='O'), size=N), 
         'foo':1, 'bar':2})
    df = df.set_index(['index', 'foo'])
    return df

def using_MultiIndex(df):
    level_values = [df.index.get_level_values(i) for i in range(index.nlevels)]
    level_values[0] = level_values[0].astype(str)
    df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(level_values)
    return df

def using_reset_index(df):
    df = df.reset_index('index')
    df['index'] = df['index'].astype(str)
    df = df.set_index('index', append=True)
    df = df.swaplevel(0, 1, axis=0)
    return df


In [81]: %%timeit df = make_df(1000)
   ....: using_MultiIndex(df)
   ....: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 693 µs per loop

In [82]: %%timeit df = make_df(1000)
   ....: using_reset_index(df)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.09 ms per loop
```